# Export cad project on image and create hotspots on specific coordinates

Tags: c#, 2d, autocad, cad, imaging

I have a 2D CAD project of an apartment, with a block inside (ex: a sink).
Through a third party software I transform the DWG drawing into a BMP. Can I create a hotspot on the BMP image at the block described above (the sink)?
In a nutshell: Can I transform the XY coordinates of my CAD project (currently in millimeters) into coordinates on my BMP image?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to call a method called something like `WorldToScreen()` or OpenGL's `gluProject()` to map object coordinates to window coordinates. Z values in the (0-1 range) can be neglected.